# How to create and register new roles in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, user-roles

I see from the official [Symfony2 doc on Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#users) that new roles can be defined besides the "classical" ones (i.e. ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, etc.).

How can I define *new roles* and register them to my Symfony2 application in order to create roles hierarchy in the *security.yml*?

Sorry to have bothered all of you! I think that the answer is simple. In fact, it seems that is sufficient to start to use a new role by starting the name with **ROLE_**.
E.g., it is possible to say **ROLE_NEWS_AUTHOR** to let only people with that role to be capable to insert a news in the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure you can simply add any roles starting with ROLE_SOMEROLE.In security.yml file there are two main part to 1.limit the access 2. Who are the memebers can access

a. access_control: Which limit the pattern and specify a role who can access.
b. role_hierarchy: here the hierarchical structure of role, for the below example an Admin user(ROLE_ADMIN) have roles ROLE_USER,ROLE_NEWS_AUTHOR. So he can access all pages of a USER and NEWS_AUTHOR.Whatever the hierarchy you can give.

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }/login any one can access this pattern
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }//block all pattern /admin/anything*
        - { path: ^/news/, roles: ROLE_NEWS_AUTHOR } //block all pattern /news/anything*
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER,ROLE_NEWS_AUTHOR]
```

In your controller you can check the roles,

```
if(TRUE ===$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') )
{
     // do something related to ADMIN
}
else if(TRUE ===$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_NEWS_AUTHOR') )
{
    // do something related to News Editor
}
```

Hope this helps you .
HAppy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Also note that roles' names should always start with "ROLE_" or Symfony won't recognize them.